# How can i check that an array of nullable integers is Null?

Tags: c#, ajax, nullable

This class is populated via an AJAX post.

```
   public class FilterViewModel
        {
            public int?[] size { get; set; }
            public decimal? Price { get; set; }
        }
```

The price property may easily be checked via

```
if (Price.HasValue)
{

}
```

But what about the size property?
Although it is declared as nullable and no data exist within, here is the burn out...

[image]

Here are the data posted

[image]

And in RAW

```
{"man":"2","size":"","color":"","Order":"0","Sorting":"0"}
```

The Ajax post is performed as

```
$.ajax({
                url: path, type: "POST", cache: "false",
                dataType: "json", contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify(postData),
                traditional: true,
                converters: {'text json': true}
            }).success(function (responseText) {
                $('#Grid').replaceWith(responseText);
            }).error(function (responseText){
                swal("Error!", "Ooops", "error");
            });
```

Comment: just for clarification purposes: `size` is an *array of nullable integers*, you don't "declare an array as nullable" - arrays are reference types.

Comment: @kaveman I totally agree, but what burned my brain, is from where the null value in position 0 was generated from.

Comment: So, is the problem with the AJAX post? How is the array generated server side?

Comment: Agree with @PeterSmith here. Something is coming in with the data on the wire - inspect with Chrome tools or Fiddler or something.

Comment: @kaveman I will try this

Comment: You also could use LINQ `model.size.All(x => x.HasValue)` This will check that all of the values in `model.size` have a value. Or `model.size.Where(x => x.HasValue)` if you wanted to get all the values that weren't null from `model.size`.

Comment: Not sure what the question is here. Obviously the array is not null since it has one item in it. That item happens to be null though.

Comment: @kaveman can you please check the update?

Comment: @OrElse it would be better to show raw string. Also consider showing code (or what controller) you use to deserialize AJAX.

Comment: How does that for loop even compile? There is no implicit conversion from int? to int.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Just updated with the Raw data. The data are sent directly to an MVC controller I will also post the AJAX part since this one is blowing my mind.

Comment: @usr there is implicit conversion from int? to int. that will just throw exception in runtime

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Does this compile on your machine? `int? a = 1;
int b =  a;`

Comment: @Magnus no. but it does in foreach statement. oh wait... lets ask a question and get 100 upvotes! just kidding

Comment: @Magnus thats suspicious cast from what resharper says.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Your right :-) It does seem to compile for a `foreach`

Comment: @OrElse Note that `""` *is not an array* (should be `[]`) - so any random result during deserialization to an array is somewhat valid...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array is reference type irrespective of what type of values is stored in it so to check for null - `size == null`.

But it looks like you actually have elements in array - you can also check if all elements are "null" with something like `size.All(x => !x.HasValue)`.

Note that above answers your question, but it is unlikely helpful to solve your problem which probably related to way request send to server. As suggested in comments using [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) to see exact request may help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Sir. I will try this one. I also updated with the posted data.